# VBA Sort Based on Two Column values

Tags: vba, excel

First let me say I have scoured the internet and this site for solutions and have come to no avail. In following the rules of the site, I have tried to develop code to fix my problem and can provide examples to the community for suggestions or help.

Goal: 
I am looking to use two lists of values (each in their own column, columns I & J for example) as an autofilter categories. I want the VBA script to select the first value in Column I and filter my table, then take the first value in column J and filter the table again. Then, the code would execute a command, reset, and restart the filter process over. This time, I want the script to select the first value in Column I again and filter the table, then select the second value in column J and filter. This whole process should repeat until all values in column J have been executed, where the filter should reset, select the second value in column I, then restart on the first value of column J.

I am able to filter my table by values in Column I using this code:

`Set Rng = ws3.Range("i2:i" & ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Sort Key1:=ws3.Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending`

I am not however able to adapt the code to consider my second list of filter values in Column J following this logic in the proper sort order

`Set Rng = ws3.Range("j2:j" & ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Sort Key1:=ws3.Range("j1"), Order1:=xlAscending`

Is there a way to link the steps together following my goal above?

Here is my complete script:

Option Explicit

```
Sub Loop2()
Dim cell As Range 'loop range
Dim Rng As Range 'range for unique values

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long 'last row in Inspection sheet
Dim i As Integer 'counter

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Inspection")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("NamedRange")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'reset autofilter
ws1.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter

'autofilter on Inspection selected
ws1.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws2.Range("C3")

'copy Column B in Table3 to NamedRange!I1
ws1.Range("B6:B20").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy 'extend range when needed
ws3.Range("I1").PasteSpecial

'Remove duplicates for unique values
ws3.Columns("I:I").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

'set range for loop and sort
Set Rng = ws3.Range("i2:i" & ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Sort Key1:=ws3.Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending

lRow = 6 'set current last row for start of ws3 summary sheet

'loop to copy row 3 from ws1 to ws2

For Each cell In Rng

    'increment last row
    i = i + 1

    With ws1
        .ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value
        .Range("B3:E3").Copy
        ws2.Range("B" & lRow + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

Next

'goto ws2.Range
Application.Goto ws2.Range("B6")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```